# Remove/change section header background color in SwiftUI List

Tags: swiftui

With a simple `List` in SwiftUI, how do I change/remove the standard background color for the section header

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<4) { section in
                Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                    ForEach(0..<4) { row in
                        Text("Row")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot with grey section header background]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No need to change appearance of all lists or do anything strange, just:

1. (Optional) Put `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())` on your `List` if you *do not* want sticky headers.
2. Set the `listRowInsets` on the section to 0.
3. Set the `Section.backgroundColor` to `clear` to remove the default color, or whatever color you want to color it.

Example:

```
List {
    Section(header: HStack {
        Text("Header")
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()

            Spacer()
    }
    .background(Color.blue)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(
        top: 0,
        leading: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        trailing: 0))
    ) {
        // your list items
    }
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle()) // Leave off for sticky headers
```

[image: Example List with Section Header Colored]

Comment: This did not work. All it did for me was push the title (eg, "Header") to the edges and make a thin blue band behind the text. The section header's gray was still present.

Comment: At first this did not work until I realized I had left .listStyle(GroupedListStyle()) on the List. Once I removed that, this solution also worked.

Comment: I will update my answer to call more attention to that step

Comment: But I do not want GroupedListStyle() I want sticky headers

Comment: I got good results with this, but had to not use Step 1, and I notice the example above itself does not set GroupedListStyle.

Comment: Okay... I finally get where I was confused.. I updated my answer to make mention of sticky headers.

Comment: If you want to have the header title accurately aligned with the rows, you can use UITableView's default separator inset as the padding: `.padding(.leading, UITableView().separatorInset.left)`. And perhaps create a constant instead of re-initializing UITableView all the time.

Comment: This seems to force all caps

Comment: Currently this solution doesn't work in landscape on iOS 14.2. It doesn't respect the safe on both sides.

Comment: How do I add top and bottom padding to the header in question?

Answer (score 17):

The suggested solutions works until you decide to `clear` your `List` header background color.

Better solutions for `List` header custom color:

1.This solution effects all of the List sections in your app: (or move it to your `AppDelegate` class)

```
struct ContentView: View {

init() {
      UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clear
    }

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0 ..< 3) { section in
            Section(header:
                    Text("Section")
            ) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 3) { row in
                    Text("Row")
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

---

2.With this solution you can have custom `List` header background color for each list in your app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
init() {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clear
}

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0 ..< 3) { section in
            Section(header:
                HStack {
                    Text("Section")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                .background(Color.blue)

            ) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 3) { row in
                    Text("Row")
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user832 Im using it in iOS 14.2 and it works

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was using NavigationLink in my section header and it was causing problem. I tried again with some changes and it worked.

Comment: For clear background this one worked for me, 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().backgroundView = UIView()'

Comment: @FRIDDAY this no longer works for iOS 16

Answer (score 12):

**In beta 4, relativeWidth was deprecated. Code updated to reflect that.**

Unfortunately, there's no quick parameter to set the background color. However, you can still do it:

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0...3) { section in
                Section(header:
                            CustomHeader(
                                name: "Section Name",
                                color: Color.yellow
                            )
                        ) {
                    ForEach(0...3) { row in
                        Text("Row")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomHeader: View {
    let name: String
    let color: Color

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text(name)
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(0).background(FillAll(color: color))
    }
}

struct FillAll: View {
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            self.color.frame(width: proxy.size.width * 1.3).fixedSize()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work really well when rotating the device, though.

Comment: iPhone XR. But setting a larger relativeWidth fixes it.

Comment: Oops. I see it. Updated the code with a larger relative width.

Comment: @AndreCarrera The answer was posted back when relativeWidth was a valid option. Code updated.

Comment: Section colors are possible (at least, they are now?) using background and edge insets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58722253/3708323

Comment: While this does work, I noticed that the color you pick isn't accurate. From my testing, all of the RGB values are dropped by -5. So, if you had the color (255, 255, 255), it becomes (250, 250, 250). Anyone know why?

Comment: Currently this solution doesn't fully work in landscape on iOS 14.2. It doesn't respect the safe area on the left side.

Answer (score 8):

I tried to use the custom header code above, and unfortunately could not get it to work in beta 6. That led me to the use of a ViewModifier:

```
public struct sectionHeader: ViewModifier{
var backgroundColor:Color
var foregroundColor:Color
public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
    .padding(20)
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 28,alignment:
    .leading)
    .background(backgroundColor)
    .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
}}
```

Which can be added to the sections in your list as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var service = someService()
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List{
            ForEach(someService.sections) {section in
                Section(header: Text(section.title).modifier(sectionHeader(backgroundColor: Color(.systemBlue), foregroundColor: Color(.white)))){
```

Hope that helps somebody!

Comment: Just make sure you do not add .listStyle() modifier to the list as that will impose its own view on the section headers.

Comment: This works on startup, but gets broken on rotation, as the width is not updated properly. Also it doesn't respect the proper safe area size in landscape.

Comment: Thanks. this is the only solution that works for me.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get the header to be clear (become white in my case) by using the custom modifiers. I needed to use listStyle() modifiers and all of the above didn't work for me.

Hope it helps someone else!

```
List {
    Section(header: HStack {
        Text("Header Text")
            .font(.headline)
            .padding()

            Spacer()
    }
    ) {
ForEach(0...3) { row in
                        Text("Row")
                    }
    }
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle()).listSeparatorStyle()

public struct ListSeparatorStyleModifier: ViewModifier {
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .singleLine
            UITableView.appearance().separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().tintColor = .clear
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // tableview background
            UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear

        }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func listSeparatorStyle() -> some View {
        modifier(ListSeparatorStyleModifier())
    }
}
```

Comment: Without GroupedListStyle this has no effect on iOS 14.2. The section background color stays the default gray. It seems that UITableViewHeaderFooterView is not a part of the picture anymore.

Comment: Perfect. worked like charm.. Keep on answering Bro

Comment: Without GroupedListStyle this has no effect

Answer (score 7):

You have to use a rectangle combined with .listRowInsets on the view for your header section

```
Section(header: headerSectionView) {
    Text("MySection")
}


private var headerSectionView: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.blue) // will make a blue header background
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        .overlay(
            Text("My Section Title")
                .padding(.horizontal), // You need this to add back the padding
            alignment: .leading
        )
}
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: It works, but if I increase the font size there is basically no top and bottom padding. How do I increase that?

Comment: You could try making the rectangle the background of the text instead of making the text an overlay. Its been a while since I answered this. I think iOS 14+ has some APIs to do this without the hacks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a better solution

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().backgroundView = .init()
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it could break at any time if apple changes the behaviour of SwiftUI lists. It probably doesn't work anymore in iOS 16 as Lists are no longer backed by UITableView. They now use UICollectionView. So you probably have to use the equivalent appearance API for collection views.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 16 you could use the `scrollContentBackground(_:)` modifier.

[Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/scrollcontentbackground(_:))

In your example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0...3) { section in
                Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                    ForEach(0...3) { row in
                        Text("Row")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do it by setting the frame of the header:

```swift
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0...3) { section in
                    Section(header:
                        Text("Section")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,alignment:.leading)
                            .background(Color.blue.relativeWidth(2))
                    ) {
                        ForEach(0...3) { row in
                            Text("Row")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I had to do this to the above to get it to work. **Section(header: Text("Group").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading).background(Color.gray))**

Comment: When I did this it mostly worked nicely, however the coloured section header bar does not reach to the sides of the display, so I'm left with a small grey section at each end which is rather disappointing. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: relativeWidth does not exist on iOS 14.2

Answer (score 1):

***iOS 16.4***

#### Removing/Changing section header BG color

Use [.listStyle(.plain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753308/swiftui-section-header-use-non-uppercase/76085010#76085010) modifier to replace sections' header default BG color with a `.clear` color. To change sections' header color, use the same modifier and add a desired BG color in ZStack.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Color.yellow.opacity(0.1).ignoresSafeArea()
            List {
                ForEach(0..<4) { section in
                    Section(header: Text("Section").font(.title)) {
                        ForEach(0..<4) { row in
                            Text("Row")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(.plain)            // clear color
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This will keep a translucent background after scroll

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, the correct way is to use `listRowBackground` in the same manner as it is used for rows, but applied to sections.

*Doing this way is also possible to use clear color.*

Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<4) { section in
                Section {
                    Text("Section #\(section)")
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

                ForEach(0..<4) { row in
                    Text("Item #\(row)")
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.red)
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also removes sticky headers in the process! nice!