# SwiftUI: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

When I use init(check the sourcecode: from Line 10), bellow error is coming.

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

If I use `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it works fine. but that should be the case know. i need to change the color of list in one contoller alone.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
struct PortalSetupView: View {
@State var title = ""
@Binding var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool
@State var name: String = ""
let datasource: [String] = ["Hi", "Hello"]

init() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // tableview background
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // cell background
}
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment:.leading){
        Text("Hey")
            .font(.system(size: 17))
            .padding(.init(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 30, trailing: 0))
        TextField("Hey there", text: $name)
        Divider().padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 0))
        List{
            Section(header: Text("My header").font(.system(size: 15))) {
                ForEach(datasource, id: \.self) { item in
                    RegionView(region: item)
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.yellow)
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

        Button(action: {
        }){
            Text("My Button").foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        }.padding()
            .background(Color("LightRed"))
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
        .navigationBarTitle("My Navigation")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .onAppear {
            self.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 18)
    }
}
struct RegionView: View {
    var region: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(region)
    }
}
```

Comment: check out this answer. It will give you some idea:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639134/8397245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with the `List`. Xcode is trying to tell you that you don't initialize all stored properties.

In the code you provided, you forgot to set an initial value for `isNavigationBarHidden` variable

Swift have a strict rule that forces you to set an initial value for every variable you define **before trying to get** it. So when you are implementing an `init()` method, you must initialize all stored properties that have no initial value before returning from the function.

Since you are using `@Binding` and you are probably setting it from previous view (due to comments), you may move the `init()` code outside of the class somewhere else like `onAppear`

You may want to do it in `onAppear` and undo it in `onDisappear` to make it look like it's only for for that controller.

Comment: That's @Binding variable and we shouldn't set any initial value as its coming from the previous screen.

Comment: You are using custom initializer, so you should should.

Comment: Ok understood. Please tell me the way to change the background color of list.

Comment: My approach is via UITableview.appearance. But i need with in the scene. Not whole app.

Comment: Look at the last line.

Comment: Sure.. really appreciated your patience.