# SwiftUI Section header - use non uppercase?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, swiftui-list

Creating a List as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header")) {
                Text("Row 1")
                Text("Row 2")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

uses uppercase text in the section header.

[image]

Is there a way to force the header text to be retain its original case?

Comment: Your code works as expected in Xcode 11.5, iOS 13. Section header is "*Header*" (capitalised but not uppercased).

Comment: Tested it in Simulator with Xcode 11.5 and it shows "Header"

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks - looks like an Xcode 12 beta issue

Comment: Still an issue in beta 2

Comment: Still an issue in beta 3

Comment: Still an issue in beta 4

Comment: Appears when Section is wrapped in a Form or List, the header is automatically styled with uppercase, colour .secondary and aligned left; if it's only in a VStack or Navigation, it's styled capitalised, colour .primary and aligned centre. Xcode 12.5, iOS 14.5

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There's a textCase(nil) modifier on Section that honours the original text case, which works on iOS 14

From Apple's developer forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655524

```
Section(header: Text("Section Title")) {
    [...]
}.textCase(nil)
```

Comment: I've postet an answer below that tries to mitigate the `#available(iOS 14.0, *)` issue! Otherwise, this is exactly the way I went as well.

Comment: You can also call textCase on header directly instead of on Section

Comment: Perfect! Also work on iOS 15.5

Answer (score 21):

For a solution that works with both iOS 13 and 14, you can make a custom modifier that only sets the textCase for iOS 14:

```
struct SectionHeaderStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                AnyView(content.textCase(.none))
            } else {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can apply it to your section like this:

```
Section(header: Text("Section Name")) {
 ...
}.modifier(SectionHeaderStyle())
```

This is an adapted version of a suggestion from apple forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650243

Comment: Shouldn't this be applied to Text("Section Name") instead of the whole section?

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add my solution which I find very convenient dealing with this issue. I simply made a custom text component that I use for section headers.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SectionHeaderText: View {
    var text: String

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            Text(text).textCase(nil)
        } else {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

I then use it like this:

```
Section(header: SectionHeaderText(text: "Info"), ...
```

Mitigates the whole situation with `#available(iOS 14.0, *)` and gets me the result I want :) Maybe this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

#### List's Style in iOS 16.4

In iOS 16.4, `.plane` and `.inset` type properties ***do provide*** the expected behavior:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Header")) {
                Text("Row 1")
                Text("Row 2")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
        // .listStyle(.inset)
    }
}
```

`.plane` and `.inset` properties help you retain the original letters' case:

| List Style | Text Appearance | Extra Features |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .automatic | HEADER | – |
| .grouped | HEADER | – |
| .inset | Header | – |
| .insetGrouped | HEADER | – |
| .plain | Header | section header's BG color is .clear |
| .sidebar | HEADER | section's disclosure indicator |